# Multiple node processes vs multiple worker threads

Tags: node.js, worker-thread

I have a project which I have to convert about 300+ different small application to node. The plan is to make one linux service per application, something like:

Service 1

```
node /le-path/le-service1.js
```

Service 2

```
node /le-path/le-service2.js
```

Etc.

So I can control them individually with `systemctl restart le-service-231`.

Now my question is, **what will be the difference if instead I use one application that spawns those 300+ as worker threads?**

Workers threads spin up their won V8 instance with a separate event loop and everything, so I'm not sure if it will have a different result (apart from the fact that controlling each process individually will require more effort).

Will it consume more/less RAM?, more/less CPU? Could I share db connections between them or something like that?

Edit:

These processes are something like:

```
while(process.exitCode == null) {
    // query the db, avg: 15s
    // do some checking (most involve other queries): avg 5s
    // maybe do some inserts or updates: avg < 1s
    // sleep, avg 30s
}
```

Since they run indefinitely I'm not sure if starting a new V8 instance every minute is a good idea

Comment: More RAM will be used with worker threads, as you'll need a master thread :) Besides that, I'm not too sure... Why don't you test yourself? Also 300+ services running on one server might not be the best of ideas. How about one service running the appropriate application on request?

Comment: @Salketer these processes are basically infinite loops who query the db. do some checking, and sometimes make some inserts or updates, then sleep for a few seconds. The "testing yourself" is what I'm trying to avoid :|

Comment: Thing is, I wouldn't have suggested it if it took more than 5 minutes... You'll build your services exactly the same way, you'll just  write your master which will simply spawn children in 10 lines of code. In the end, having a master may become pretty handy for monitoring and stuff.

Comment: hummm, so the answer is "makes basically no difference", dang